# Best way to transcode/stream media from my Laptop?

Tags: windows, ios, media-player, streaming, server

I am lazy, so I download stuff to my laptop, and stream these to my tablet (and smartphone).

I am looking for a **DLNA/UpNp** server that can help me do the following.

**Musts**:

1. Streams anything, including MKV
2. Support for AC3 transcoding

**Awesomeness**:

3. Support for transcoding with multiple bitrates (from **11ac** speeds (*866mbps*) to **11n** speeds (*72mbps*)
4. Transcoding on the fly, with support for **SEEK**

I have tried:

- Minidlna, (only 1).
- Windows Media Server (only 1 and 2)

Can anyone point out some **FREE** utilities to achieve these. I know about *ffmpeg*, which I currently use as a fallback for **AC3**, but seems too much effort.

Comment: Not tried it myself, but did you take a look at [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/download/) (formerly known as XBMC)? Supports all kind of platforms, is feature rich, free.

Answer (score 1):

[UMS (Universal Media Server)](http://www.universalmediaserver.com/) Should cover all your points.

In particular I never had problems seeking, it supports almost any existing video format (ffmpeg-powered) and it automatically uses all the available bandwidth for maximum quality (but you can set a max bandwidth/bitrate if you want)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it on and off for quite some time now. And Plex should have you covered on all your requirements. https://plex.tv

Plex also offers paid features to use their interface to bind devices together remotely, but for your needs it should be free.

Comment: Pled transcodes for the browser version, but not dlna

Comment: As I understand, plex is using profiles to decide whether to transcode or not, including on DLNA